# Logstash Metrics Output

Tags: logging, output, logstash, metrics, logstash-configuration

I'm using metrics filter in two fields (backend_name) (http_request) but my output is not working, I'm trying to write this to a csv. someone have a idea what is going on?

```
grok {
    match => {"message" =>'%{HAPROXYHTTP}'}
}

metrics {
    meter => [ "%{backend_name} %{http_request}" ]
    add_tag => "metric"
}

output {
    file {
        path => "/home/netcool/Desktop/teste.csv"
        codec => line { format => "rate: %{[%{backend_name} %{http_request}] %[rate_1m]}" }
    }
}

stdout { 
    codec => rubydebug 
}
```

Comment: can you please review my improved formatting of your Code? i have removed a (I think) unecessary curly brace and added a (I think) necessary one. thanks!

Comment: @cramopy Seems good to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The filter (`metrics` & `grok`) plugins should be in the brackets of a `filter {}` and the output plugin `stdout` should be in `output{}`.

For your configuration, it would look like this:

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => {"message" =>'%{HAPROXYHTTP}'}
    }

    metrics {
        meter => [ "%{backend_name} %{http_request}" ]
        add_tag => "metric"
    }
}

output {
    file {
        path => "/home/netcool/Desktop/teste.csv"
        codec => line { format => "rate: %{[%{backend_name} %{http_request}] %[rate_1m]}" }
    }

    stdout { 
        codec => rubydebug 
    }
}
```